# read() not waiting for input

Tags: c, linux, input, io, stdin

I've got kind of strange problem. I was working on a simple program which was supposed to send data taken from stdin over the net to another instance of this program, which should send the data directly to stdout. But it didn't work as it should, sending just a part of the data. After that, I managed to find out where problem is in the reading from stdin:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define SIZE 1024

int main(void) {
    char *buffer;
    int read_bytes;

    buffer = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*SIZE);

    while ((read_bytes = read(STDIN_FILENO,buffer,SIZE)) == SIZE) {
        write(STDOUT_FILENO,buffer,SIZE);
        fprintf(stderr,"read %d bytes\n",read_bytes);
    }
    fprintf(stderr,"read %d bytes\n",read_bytes);
    write(STDOUT_FILENO,buffer,read_bytes);
    return 0;
}
```

(this is just to simply demostrate the problem, not actual part of original code)
It all works as it should (-> resending data from stdin to stdout) until I sourced from something which took more time, for example:

```
find / | ./the_programme > output.file
```

Output stopped after some thousand bytes, and I'm really confused why (it definitely wasn't finished). I tried clearing O_NONBLOCK flag on STDIN_FILENO with fcntl, but it didn't help at all. I am probably missing something terribly basic here, but neither man pages nor googling helped me.

Comment: Did that. I should've asked in a bit different way: is there a way to make read() wait until requested bytes are available (or EOF is found)? I was a bit tired, hope that justifies my confused question...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the manual (`man 2 read`):

> Return Value:
>
> On success, the number of bytes read is returned (zero
>   indicates end of file), and the file position is advanced by this
>   number. It is **not an error** if this number is smaller than the number
>   of bytes requested; this may happen for example because fewer bytes
>   are actually available right now (maybe because we were close to
>   end-of-file, or because we are reading from a pipe, or from a
>   terminal), or because read() was interrupted by a signal.

```
while ((read_bytes = read(STDIN_FILENO,buffer,SIZE)) > 0) {
    write(STDOUT_FILENO,buffer,read_bytes);
    fprintf(stderr,"read %d bytes\n",read_bytes);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I know its not error when read() returns smaller number than requested, but I thought using fcntl() and clearing O_NONBLOCK should make read() wait for input (until requested bytes are available). Is this possible? I should have put the question that way. I'm sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: by default O_NONBLOCK is not enabled, so you don't have to clear it. and no, it's not possible to do that.